# "WebSocket connection to failed" - VSC and Rect

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, localhost

I get this error in my console for each react project I work on. I run project on localhost:3000 starting with npm from Mac terminal or VSC terminal. I'm new in this and I really hope someone can help me fixing this.
Thank you so much in advance

I added some new extensions in VSC that maybe had changed some settings, but I disabled them and the error still exists.

Comment: I installed back Console Ninja and run npm from vac terminal. Now the error has gone.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error in dev tools.

To confirm, in the dev tools network tab, click the location of the error, VM23:1.

Scroll to the top of the file to confirm it's Console Ninja.

In my case, a restart of VS and VSC resolved the error, but I'll update if it comes back.

[image: Error:]

[image: Click here]

[image: Scroll to the top of this file]

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/wallabyjs/console-ninja/issues/9

Or

Just clean your builder cache: Vite, Next, etc... the error goes away after that

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35670508)